# How do I run an AIR app on the device?

Tags: applications, adobe-air

I've installed Adobe Air, and I have a few AIR apps that I have built over time and am curious to see how they will look running on the device, but am not clear on how to install them.

I uploaded the app to the phone but clicking on the .air file doesn't provoke an installation process, instead, it just opens the browser and attempts to display it (and fails, obviously).

What to to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were the apps developed using Above Air for Android? There seems to be a distinction between the two SDKs. Look at this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/august2010/articles/article1/index.html?trackingid=HRTDI) for all the info on getting started. Even if some of the info is redundant, it does have a section on deployment to the phone.

Answer (score 3):

*Here's an answer for regular end users who happen upon this question because they are confused about the whole "Air" thing, wondering "how to install and adobe air based app?"*

If you phone doesn't already have it installed, get the [Adobe Air app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adobe-air/com.adobe.air).  Now you can download and install any of the [apps that are based on Adobe Air](http://www.appbrain.com/apps/popular/adobe-air/).  There's really not a lot to it for end users.  Even if you don't install the Adobe Air app and you try to install an Air based app, it will automatically direct you to install Adobe Air.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [video](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/installing_an_air_application_on_android.html) that shows how to turn an air app into into an apk file.  I'm not a dev so I have no idea what he's talking about but it sounds like what you want to do so it may help.