# Can someone describe how publishing an Adobe Air file on Android works?

Tags: adobe-air

I'm familiar with Adobe Air and I noticed it is on the Market. Does it accept .AIR files for install? If so, how does Air make adjustments for the small screen? Does air have access to all the neat features of Android? Such as access the contacts or the SD card? Need some help understanding how my Air application will perform on Droid. Should I still develop Android specif apps, or is Air ready for prime time?

Comment: This is relevant to Android users who want to run Air apps, so I've answered below.  However, for development questions please use http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I assumed that this site covers Android development as well. It just says Android Enthusiasts... Oh well, I got confused. Still a relevant question through.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq). Development questions still go on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/how-do-i-run-an-air-app-on-the-device

Comment: Could be a duplicate, but the answer doesn't answer my question completely. Sure the Phone SDK is different than the Adobe SDK, it still doesn't tell me if other air applications will run on droid or how they will perform. I don't want to use air on my droid if clicking on an Application is going to hurt my phone (in a matter of speaking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You still need to develop Android-specific apps](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2010/10/publishing-air-apps-to-the-android-market/), but you should be able to reuse most of your code if you a rewriting a desktop Air app for Android.  So users can't just grab a regular Air app and run it on their phone, unfortunately.

Comment: So I couldn't download say Jade from adobe air and run it on Droid. The application has to be modified to work specifically with android... That doesn't seem like an easy feat to me.

Comment: Jade wouldn't work, no.  I assume there are simple apps that might work without modification, but with anything complicated you can't really expect it to just run -- the resources, input methods, etc. available on a phone are very different than a PC.